# 2-Dimensional Volume of $M:= \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3:x^2+y^2+z^2=1, a\leq x \leq b, z \geq 0 \}$

Tags: lebesgue-integral, submanifold

with $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $-1 <a<b<1$.

I tried to compute the 2 dimensional volume of the set M (the area) by submanifolds. But I have hard times finding an right atlas for it. I tried it with $\phi(x,z)=(x,\sqrt{1-x^2-z^2},z)$ but it seems like that it doesn't work with this one and now I am stuck. So how can I find an easy way to compute this by submanifolds? What am I missing?

As hint we got $\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}=\sin^{-1}(\frac{x}{a}) +C$. Maybe for  the late part of the solution.

The question was asked before [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4511866/volume-of-m-x-y-z-in-mathbb-r3x2y2z2-1-a-leq-x-leq-b-z-geq-0) but, I guess the questioner didn't provide the right and enough information for the problem.
)

Comment: You could consider each side individually. E.g. in the case that
$0 < b$ you can parametrise the upper surface of the "right" half sphere via
$$
\begin{align*}
\Phi \colon  [ 0, \arcsin\!\left( b\right) ]\times [ 0, 2\pi ], \quad 
\Phi (\theta , \varphi )
=\begin{bmatrix}
  \sin\!\left( \theta \right) \cos\!\left( \varphi \right) \\ 
\sin\!\left( \theta \right) \sin\!\left( \varphi \right) 
\\
\cos\!\left( \theta \right) 
\end{bmatrix} 
.\end{align*}
$$
A similar procedure follows for $a < 0$, $b < 0$, ...

Comment: So in the case that $b > 0$ considered above you'd compute the surface of the area parametrised by 
$\Phi $ and then have to add the surface of the right cut, which will be 
$\pi ( 1 - b^{2})$.

Comment: Suggestions: 1. Your chart/parametrization works, but spherical coordinates (Richard's comment, modulo permutation of coordinates) are arguably easier; 2. Forget $z \geq 0$ to start; the area of the zone $a \leq x \leq b$ can be found (or confirmed) by "Archimedes's hat box theorem" (_q.v._). 3. Because the plane $z = 0$ is longitudinal compared to $x = a$ and $x = b$, the area you want is half the area of the zone.

Comment: Thanks for your answers so far. I am back at the problem after some time. And with a new question: I could also parametrize like $\phi(x,z)=(x, , y \sqrt{1-x^2-y^2})$, right? And then I don't need to consider each sides individually with $U:= \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^:x^2+y^2 < 1, a\leq x \leq b \}$.  And I see that spherical coordiantes are way better but I dont see where you got your $arcsin(b)$ from. Thanks so far.